# sidebar isn't showing, what's wrong w/ this code?

Tags: php, sidebar

Here's what I have in my sidebar.php:

```
  <aside id="sidebar">
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo '<a href="/community"><img id="visit-the-forums" src="'. bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/visit-the-forums.png" alt="Check out the Forums!" /></a>'
    } else {
      echo '<a href="/community"><img id="join-the-forums" src="'. bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/join-the-forums.png" alt="Join the Forums!" /></a>'
    }
    ?>
    <a id="side-ad">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/ipad-ad.png" alt="iPad 2 Giveaway!" />
    </a>
  </aside>
```

For some reason, it doesn't show (not even in the markup) for any of the pages. I've double-checked all of the other templates to make sure `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` is included. Is there something wrong w/ the code above?

Edit: I should note that the below works, that is, without the if/else statement.

```
  <aside id="sidebar">
    <a href="/community"><img id="join-the-forums" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/join-the-forums.png" alt="Join the Forums!" /></a>
    <a id="side-ad">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/ipad-ad.png" alt="iPad 2 Giveaway!" />
    </a>
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the markup after `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` show up?

I would guess that this is a silent PHP error, as your lines within the if/else block do not end with semi-colons. :)

Answer (score 3):

The semicolons should be present at the end of each echo within if/else.

To help you find some mistakes it is a good practice to activate the WordPress debug variable, so you get some notices about your code.

You can do it replacing false for true in the **WP_DEBUG** var.
Find in your wordpress root instalation for the file `wp-config.php` , backup it, after open/edit and search for the line containig the

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

change to true, like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Now, when opening you wite to test your code, if there is some error or notice, you will get in the top of the page. Even in Dasbord.